# Kendo Grid Filter - Problems with check marks

Tags: angularjs, filter, kendo-ui, grid

I'm using a Grid Filterable (mode = row) and I have discovered that it does not filter as I expected in a Text Field. 
If I look for Maria i would like to receive all names with Maria, María, Marïa...
I want to use it without write check marks.

Is it possible?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.